# A surjective homomorphism between finite free modules of the same rank

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

I know a proof of the following theorem using determinants.
For some reason, I'd like to know a proof without using them.

> **Theorem**
>   Let $A$ be a commutative ring.
>   Let $E$ and $F$ be finite free modules of the same rank over $A$.
>   Let $f:E → F$ be a surjective $A$-homomorphism.
>   Then $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I think there is a similar result in Atiyah Macdonald chapter 2 no? The proof for it is using the Cayley Hamilton theorem, does that count as using determinants?

Comment: I cannot find the result in the book. Could you tel me the proposition No.?

Comment: It's in the exercises exercise 11 of chapter 2.

Comment: Dear @Benjamin, Atiyah-Macdonald assume  noetherianness. Actually you don't need noetherian, nor even freeness of the module. Only that the module  be  finitely generated: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/39179/3217) (where you can find a reference, Makoto)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I believe in chapter 2 they haven't covered the noetherian condition yet no?

Comment: @George I know Vasconcelos's theorem and I think it's somewhat tricky. Since the title theorem assumes freeness of modules, I guess there is a simpler proof(actualy there is at least such one using determinants).

Comment: Dear @Benjamin, well, no, they haven't covered the noetherian condition yet in Chapter 2. But on the other hand I have just checked that exercise 11 doesn't address Makoto's question !

Comment: Dear Makoto, if you know Vasconcelos's theorem, I have nothing to add: sorry.

Comment: @Benjamin I think exercise 11 of chapter 2 is different from the title theorem, no?

Comment: @George Not at all. Sorry I didn't mention the Vasconcelos's theorem in the first place.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Perhaps I am confused....

Comment: See M. Orzech, "Onto Endomorphisms are Isomorphisms", Amer. Math. Monthly 78 (1971), 357--362.  To quote from the first section "We shall begin Section 3 by indicating several methods of approaching the proof of Vasconselos's theorem. Two of these methods, both known by Vasconselos, have in common the use of the theory of determinants over a commutative ring. We shall show that Theorem 1 can be proved without the use of determinants."

Comment: @KCd That's interesting! Thanks.

Comment: @George Atiyah-Macdonald's Exercise 6.1 is good enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: @KCd I like Orzech's proof(though there are a few typos). It is conceptual enough. Since the module is finitely generated, it can be reduced to a Noetherian module case which is Atiyah-Macdonald's Exercise 6.1.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/239419/303887

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can show that every commutative ring is *stably finite* (see Lam's *Lectures on Modules and Rings* first 10 pages or so) which means that if $R^n\cong R^n\oplus N$, then $N=0$.

If you have a surjection $f:M\rightarrow M'$, then $M/\ker(f)\cong M'$, but $M'$ being projective implies that $0\rightarrow \ker(f)\rightarrow M\rightarrow M/\ker{f}\rightarrow 0$ splits, and so $M\cong \ker(f)\oplus M'$, whence $\ker{f}=\{0\}$.

Comment: The Lam's book proves that every commutative ring is stably finite using *determinants*. Thanks, any way.

Comment: @MakotoKato Well rather than give up because the answer is not given to you on a platter, an idea might be to prove *that* without determinants... or if you are willing to prove for me that it is *impossible* not to use determinants, I would be interested in seeing *that*.

Comment: I've got an idea. I think we can assume that A is a local ring by localizing at every maximal ideal of the ring. –

Comment: For the record, the Lam's proof using *determinants* is exactly the same as I had in my mind when I asked the title question.

Comment: By localizing at every maximal ideal of $A$, we can assume $A$ is a local ring.
Let $I$ be the maximal ideal of $A$.
Let $k = A/I$.
Let $K = Ker(f)$.
Since $0\rightarrow K\rightarrow E\rightarrow F\rightarrow 0$ splits,
$0\rightarrow K\otimes k\rightarrow E\otimes k\rightarrow F\otimes k\rightarrow 0$ is exact.
Hence $K\otimes k = 0$.
By Nakayama's lemma, $K = 0$ as desired.

Comment: @MakotoKato For the non-psychic editors' benefit, it would be good to include what you had in mind when you wrote the question :) I'm glad you found an approach you like!

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is not complete. See the comments below.**

---

The modules $E$ and $F$ being free of finite rank $n$ over $A$ means that they each have a finite basis over $A$. Take $y \in F$, and since $f$ is surjective some $x \in E$ maps to $y$. Pick a basis for $\langle e_1, \dots, e_n \rangle$ of $E$ over $A$, so $x = a_1e_1 + \dotsb + a_ne_n$ for some $a_i \in A$. Then for our arbitrary element $y \in F$,
$$
y = f(a_1e_1 + \dotsb + a_ne_n) = a_1f(e_1) + \dotsb + a_nf(e_n)
\,
$$
so $\langle f(e_1),\dotsc, f(e_n)\rangle$ generates $F$. Since $F$ has the same rank as $E$, these generators must form a basis (**this needs to be proven. See [darij grinberg's comment below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153516/a-surjective-homomorphism-between-finite-free-modules-of-the-same-rank/2900918?noredirect=1#comment5992177_2900918)**). Since these generators form a basis
$$
0 = f(\alpha_1e_1 + \dotsb + \alpha_ne_n) = \alpha_1f(e_1) + \dotsb + \alpha_nf(e_n)
$$
only when the $\alpha_i$ are all zero, so $f$ is injective and hence an isomorphism. ${_\square}$

I don't see why we need $A$ to be a commutative ring. Since we're specifying that $E$ and $F$ have the same rank I assume they have the [invariant dimension property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number). Otherwise commutivity would imply this. Also we're only talking about a single map $f \colon E \to F$ and don't need to talk about the module structure on $\mathrm{Hom}_R(E,F)$, for which we need $R$ to be commutative.

Also I've seen it asked as an exercise, *is this still true if we assume $f$ is injective instead of surjective?* The answer is no, looking at the counterexample $\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z}$ where $1 \mapsto 2$, regarding $\mathbf{Z}$ as a rank $1$ free module over itself.

Comment: "Since F has the same rank as E, these generators must form a basis": not obvious, and only true for commutative rings.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I see that's not obvious now. But it is true though, right? The elements $f(e_i)$ actually *are* linearly independent? Do you know a way to proceed with this line of proof, or would you recommend just accepting the approach in [rschwieb's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/153536/167197) as the most reasonable way? Also, I still don't see what noncommutativity breaks here. Do you know an illuminating counterexample to this where $R$ is noncommutative? Thank you. :)

Comment: It is true, but it is equivalent to the original question. In particular, it does not generalise to noncommutative rings that don't have the invariant basis property.