# Conditions on Hartshorne exercise II.7.1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne, "Algebraic Geometry," Exercise II.7.1, reads:

> Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ be a locally ringed space, and let $f : \mathscr{L} \to \mathscr{M}$ be a surjective map of invertible sheaves on $X$.  Show that $f$ is an isomorphism.

To prove this, I note that a morphism of sheaves is injective (resp. surjective) iff it is injective (resp. surjective) on stalks.  Thus $f_P$ is surjective for each $P \in X$.  Since $\mathscr{L}$ and $\mathscr{M}$ are invertible, $\mathscr{L}_P \cong \mathscr{M}_P \cong \mathcal{O}_{X, P}$ as $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}$-modules.  From commutative algebra, a surjective endomorphism of finitely-generated modules over any ring is in fact an automorphism, so $f$ is an isomorphism on stalks and thus an isomorphism of sheaves.

This argument sounds fine to me, but now I'm worried because I didn't use many of the conditions in the problem -- I could weaken it to an arbitrary (rather than locally-) ringed space, to any locally free sheaves of the same rank or even to something a bit weaker (namely that $\mathscr{L}$ and $\mathscr{M}$ are locally isomorphic), etc.

Have I missed something here?  Or does the result hold in much wider generality without any modification?

Comment: But the stalks of the structure sheaf of a ringed space need not be local rings...?

Comment: I only need that they're rings, so far as I can see...

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, I suppose so. I think the intended solution was to directly appeal to Nakayama's lemma in the local case.

Comment: +1 for having noticed that despite appearances, once you strip the theorem of its fancy algebraic geometry disguise, it becomes a very easy fact about general commutative rings.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I remember being a bit confused by this problem as well, for the same reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel McLaury, you are right. The same proof works in the following generality: If $X$ is a ringed space, $F,G$ are $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules such that for every $x \in X$ there is some isomorphism $F_x \cong G_x$ and this $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module is finitely generated, then every epimorphism $F \to G$ is an isomorphism. The reason is that $F_x \to G_x$ is an isomorphism for every $x \in X$, by Nakayama. Of course this argument simplifies when $F,G$ are invertible, see Georges' answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is elementary undergraduate algebra and has  nothing to do with local rings nor Nakayama:

One reduces  to show  that given a commutative ring $A$, any surjective $A$-linear map $f:A\to A$ is in fact bijective.
Since $f(x)=f(x\cdot 1)=x\cdot f( 1)$, the map $f$ has the form $f(x)=u\cdot x$ (with $u:=f(1)$).
Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $v\in A$ with $1=f(v)=u\cdot v$ .
This implies that $u$ is invertible and $f$ is thus bijective with inverse $f^{-1}(y)= v\cdot y$ .

Comment: Hmm... If this is Hartshorne's intended argument, then I don't see why he stipulated that $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ be a *locally* ringed space, since it seems to work just fine for an arbitrary ringed space.  If he expected the reader to apply Nakayama, as Zhen Lin hypothesizes, then that could explain the presence of the hypothesis.

Comment: But, yes, this is surely the quickest and easiest-to-understand way of answering the question as stated!

Comment: Dear Daniel, one possibility is that arbitrary ringed spaces are not really studied  in the book and that Hartshorne didn't bother to state his exercise in the greatest possible generality.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury May be useful: Look at Georges' answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432659/favourite-applications-of-the-nakayama-lemma).

Comment: @user38268, not only am I aware of that result, I'm using it in my argument above!

Comment: Another formulation: if $f:A\twoheadrightarrow A$, let $I$ be the kernel then $A\simeq A/I$ but $I (A/I)=0$ so that $I=0$ in $A$ and so $f$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You have used that $f_P$ is an endomorphism.  At the very least, you need to assume that $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ are locally isomorphic.

Comment: Ah, I meant to say "arbitrary locally free modules *of the same rank*" there.  Let me fix that.

Comment: Anyway, my point was that the condition that the sheaves were invertible seemed only to be giving me that they were locally isomorphic to each other.