# Rank of free submodules of a free module over a commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples

Free modules over a commutative ring $R$ with $1$ have well-defined rank.

> I have been wondering if there is a ring $R$ such that there are free modules $M'\subset M$ with $\operatorname{rank}(M')>\operatorname{rank}(M)$ for a while, but can't come up with examples or a proof of the contrary in general.

All I know is that this never happens if $R$ is a domain, since you can consider $M'$ and $M$ as vector spaces over the fraction field of $R$.

Comment: This can't happen. See Corollary 5.11 of Keith Conrad's notes on exterior powers: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf

Comment: This has been asked at least 5 times on math.SE.

Answer (score 14):

### Lemma

One way to see why free submodules of free modules over a commutative ring have to have lesser or equal rank uses this lemma. The lemma is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405618/using-nakayamas-lemma-to-prove-isomorphism-theorem-for-finitely-generated-free?lq=1), that surjections of finitely generated modules over commutative rings are necessarily isomorphisms.

If $R^m$ were isomorphic to a submodule of $R^n$ and $m>n$, you would easily be able to construct a projection of that submodule onto $R^n$ which would then necesarily be an isomorphism, but that is impossible since we have decided ranks of f.g. free modules are well-defined for commutative rings.

---

### Bonus (=ignorable)

Rings which have well defined ranks for their finitely generated free modules are said to have the [IBN property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number). This property is: "If $R^n$ and $R^m$ are isomorphic as right $R$ modules, then $m=n$."

The proof that a commutative ring $R$ has the IBN is pretty easy if you can make a few jumps. First of all, after picking a basis for $R^n$ and $R^m$, one can see this amounts to finding an $n\times m$ matrix $A$ and an $m\times n$ matrix $B$, both over $R$, such that $AB=I_n$ and $BA=I_m$. The second observation is that we can pick a maximal ideal $M$ of $R$ and project from $R$ onto $R/M$, a field. But if you apply this projection to the entries of $A$ and $B$, you wind up with two matrices which are mutually inverse over a field: but that implies $m=n$ since we know dimension is well-defined for vector spaces.

There are examples for rings in general, but not for commutative rings. The familiar example for rings with ranks which aren't well defined are that of [full linear rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_linear_ring#Full_linear_rings).

Take $R$ to be the ring of transformations of a countable infinite dimensional vector space. It's not hard to show that $R\cong R^2$ as $R$ modules, and hence by induction $R\cong R^n$ for any $n\in \Bbb N$, and then $R^n\cong R^m$ for any positive integers $n,m$.

If by "rank" you are thinking of the $n$ and $m$ above, then this example shows that "rank" of a free module isn't always well defined.

Moreover, if this didn't convince you already, take $R^2$ and look at the submodule $R\times \{0\}$. The submodule is still isomorphic to $R^m$ for whatever positive integer $m$ you like.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all this but the first sentence in my post says that all commutative rings have IBN; your example in the non-commutative case is the usual one that motivates proving this fact.

Comment: Dear @JessicaB : I was not done editing. In the interval I had added the proof for commutative rings. Hope you find the outline of the proof helpful. I think I will reorganize it to prioritize the proof.

Comment: Dear @rschwieb, I don't think the OP was asking for a proof that rank is well-defined for free modules over commutative rings with identity. She was asking if it's possible to have a free submodule with larger rank than the ambient free module.

Comment: Dear @KeenanKidwell : The problem is that nobody is willing to wait more than 15 minutes for an anwer to be complete. The solution I just finished writing *does* show that. Of course, I'm never going to win a speed race against answers that are just links to complete solutions :)

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Your eyes aren't fooling you though, I did initially key off the first sentence as a question rather than a statement, which led me down this path. In light of that, I should probably reduce that cruft.

Comment: Dear @rschwieb, I didn't mean to infer that your answer wasn't helpful or anything like that. I learned a different approach from your edit to the one outlined in the notes to which I linked, so +1. And you're right, I should wait a reasonable amount of time for people to edit their answers. My apologies.

Comment: Dear @KeenanKidwell : No don't apologize :) I can totally understand how it looks from the other side of the screen and I don't expect people to be watching their wristwatches either. I will be sure to read up on the solution you gave as well, since I want to develop my sense of what you can do with exterior algebra...