# Generating connected module over a connected $K$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, graded-modules

I have an algebraic question that I cannot solve. It is extracted from Adams and Margolis' [paper](http://people.virginia.edu/%7Emah7cd/Foundations/Adams,%20Margolis%20-%20Modules%20over%20the%20Steenrod%20Algebra.pdf) on modules over the Steenrod Algebra. Here is the problem :

> Let $K$ be a commutative ring with unit, $R$ a connected $K$-algebra (not commutative in my case), i.e., graded as $R \cong K \oplus R_1 \oplus R_2 \oplus \cdots$, and $M$ be a connected $R$-module, i.e., only positively graded (no condition on $M_0$, but I am okay to assume $M_0 \cong K$, only as a $K$-module).
>
> Consider elements $\{m_i\} \in M$ such that $\{ 1 \otimes m_i \} \in K \otimes_R M$ form a $K$-basis.

(Note that $K \otimes_R M \cong M / I(R)M$ where $I(R)$ is the augmentation ideal for the canonical augmentation here, so another way to see it is that $\{ \overline{m_i} \}$ form a $K$-basis)

Then they claim that "the following facts are well known and easily proved:"

> 1. The $\{ m_i \}$ $R$-generates $M$.
> 2. If $M$ is $R$-free, then the $\{ m_i \}$ are an $R$-basis of $M$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Regarding the comment above, you may wish to see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma#Graded_version

Comment: Well, if $m_i$ are not homogeneous I don't think your claims hold.

Comment: @MannyReyes Thank you, I was not aware of a non commutative Nakayama's Lemma. I'm looking into it.

Comment: @user Thanks, I believe you are right. However, I only consider homogeneous elements, ideals, etc in the graded setting, so this is not a problem for my application :).

Comment: Actually the comment of Manny Reyes was a complement of my first comment here where I suggested you for 1. to use graded Nakayama, but I've deleted that comment since I've realized that you didn't assume $m_i$ homogeneous and then can't apply graded Nakayama.

Comment: The quoted paper is cryptical about the conditions when the two claims hold and as they are stated is hard to believe that really hold. Only the OP (who I assumed that read the paper) can say exactly what the paper needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If $(m_i)$ are homogeneous, then use [Nakayama Lemma, graded version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma#Graded_version).
2. Since $M$ is free it has a basis $(x_j)_{j\in J}$ and this remains so in $K\otimes_RM$, therefore $|J|=|I|$. (For the sake of simplicity let's assume $J=I$.) Now let $f:M\to M$ given by $f(x_i)=m_i$. Then $f$ is surjective, and using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239364/surjective-endomorphisms-of-finitely-generated-modules-are-isomorphisms) $f$ is bijective, so $(m_i)$ is a basis. (Here I need $M$ *finitely generated* and I don't have a proof if remove this condition.)

Comment: This looks good. I believe it is possible to allow $M$ to be of finite type in the case I am interested (when the ground algebra is finitely generated). Thanks.