# "Graded free" is stronger than "graded and free"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, graded-modules, graded-rings

[This topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557139/generating-connected-module-over-a-connected-k-algebra) suggested me the following question:

> If $R$ is a commutative graded ring and $F$ a graded $R$-module which is free, then can we conclude that $F$ has a homogeneous basis (that is, a basis consisting of homogeneous elements)?

In general the answer is negative, and such an example can be found in Nastasescu, Van Oystaeyen, *Methods of Graded Rings*, page 21. But their example is not quite usual, and

> I'd like to know if however the property holds for positively graded $K$-algebras, for example.

If not, then maybe someone can provide a generic example when the property holds.

Comment: It almost never holds. Twist the grading by any (non-graded) automorphism.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: What do you mean by "almost never" ? Is there a precise measure for this quantity in the current context?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg - I'm not quite getting your suggestion, can you elaborate? What's $F$? Automorphism of $R$ as a ring or $R$ as an $F$-module? And what do you use the automorphism for? To define the action of $R$ on $F$? Please clarify?

Answer (score 8):

It is not clear to me in the previous answer what assumptions are being made on the $\mathbb{N}$-graded algebra $R$ (particularly, what assumptions are made on $R_0$), but I'll try to be very careful here. Suppose that $R = \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty R_n$ and that $R$ is *connected*, meaning that $R_0 = K$.  Let's say that a graded $R$-module $M = \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} M_n$ is *bounded below* if $M_n = 0$ for $n \ll 0$.

Then I claim that **if $R$ is connected, then every bounded-below graded $R$-module that is free has a homogeneous basis.**

This can be deduced, even in a noncommutative setting, in the very informative Section 2 of the paper [*The structure of AS regular algebras* by Minamoto and Mori](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870810004226), especially Lemma 2.6.  (In fact, one can try to drop further assumptions; I suspect that it's enough to assume $R_0$ is a [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring) local ring, not necessarily commutative, in which case every bounded-below graded projective left module would probably be free with a homogeneous basis.)

I'll sketch an argument here; it's essentially the same as the one in the answer already given by user26857.  The key observation is that the [graded Nakayama's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma#Graded_version) works for bounded-below modules, of which finitely generated graded modules form a special case.

**Proof of claim:** Supposing that $F$ is graded, bounded-below, and free, fix a set of homogeneous elements $\{x_i\} \subseteq F$ whose images $\overline{x_i} \in F/R_+ F$ form a homogeneous basis for the graded vector space.  We get a graded map from a bounded-below graded free module $\phi \colon G = \bigoplus R(-l_i) \to F$, where each $l_i = \deg(x_i)$, sending the $i$th basis element to $x_i$.  Nakayama implies that this is a "minimal projective cover," in the sense that $\phi$ is surjective and $\ker(\phi) \subseteq R_+ G$. Since $F$ is free we have $G \cong F \oplus L$ for the graded submodule $L = \ker(\phi) \subseteq G$.  But now $$L = \ker(\phi) \subseteq R_+ G = R_+(F \oplus L) = R_+ F \oplus R_+ L.$$ Inspecting this direct sum decomposition, we must in fact have $L \subseteq R_+ L$. Nakayama now implies that $\ker(\phi) = L = 0$. Thus $F \cong G$ as graded modules, so that $F$ has a homogeneous basis.  QED

What I would *really* like to know is what happens if one drops the bounded-below assumption.  **Is there an example of a graded module over a connected graded (commutative) ring $R$ that is not bounded-below, and which does not have a homogeneous basis?**

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I think the key step I was missing when thinking about this before is the fact that $L$ is a direct summand of $G$, so $L\subseteq R_+G$ implies $L\subseteq R_+L$.

Comment: @MannyReyes - does "graded vector space" just mean a vector space with a distinguished direct sum decomposition indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith yes that's right. Equivalently, it is a graded module over the field $K$, the latter viewed as a graded algebra concentrated in degree zero.

Comment: @MannyReyes - thank you! Two more questions for you if you don't mind. (1) do you know if the terminology *connected* as you're using it is related to usage I've heard before that the Spec is connected as a top. space? I can't see how it would be related. (2) I'm trying to understand to what extent this proof still works if $R_0$ is a p.i.d. rather than a field. The use I can see of the fieldness of $R_0$ is to guarantee that $F/R_+F$ is free as a module over $R_0$, right?

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith: The term "connected" comes rather from algebraic topology. If $R$ is the cohomology graded ring of a space $X$ with coefficients in $K$, then X is path-connected iff $R_0=K$.

Comment: @EricWofsey - Thank you, got it.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith I think I agree with what you say in (2), that $R_0$ being a field is useful because it guarantees $F/R_+ F$ is free over $R_0$.  And thanks to Eric Wofsey for addressing question (1).  I would also point out that if $R_0$ has no idempotents (as in the case when $R_0 = K$), then $R$ is "graded-connected" in the sense that there is no graded isomorphism $R \cong R_1 \times R_2$ for graded rings $R_i$.

Comment: @MannyReyes - the situation is even better than that. If $R_0$ has connected spectrum, then $R$ has connected spectrum. (I.e. no need to distinguish a concept of "graded-connected" from "connected" in the sense of connected spectrum.) Pf: Let $x = x_0 + \dots + x_n$ be an idempotent, split into homogeneous components. Looking component by component at $x^2 = x$ lets you conclude first that $x_0=0$ or $1$ and then by induction (starting with $i=1$) that $x_i=0$ for $i > 0$. Thus a graded connected $A$-algebra is connected in both senses, if $A$ is connected.

Comment: @MannyReyes : how do you say that $\phi$ is surjective and $\ker \phi \subseteq R_+G$ ?

Comment: @users - The homomorphism is constructed to induce an isomorphism between $G/R_+ G$ and $F/R_+ F$, so its kernel must be contained in $R_+ G$. The fact a homomorphism inducing a surjective map $G/R_+ G \to F/R_+ F$ must itself be surjective is a common corollary of Nakayama's Lemma; see the "ungraded" version here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma#Module_epimorphisms

Comment: @MannyReyes : By $R(l_i)$ where $l_i :=\deg x_i$ , you mean the homogenous part of $R$ in which $x_i$ lies , right ? And what do you mean by " the $i$-th basis element " ?

Comment: @users The notation $R(l)$ refers to the "twist" of the graded module $R$, so that the graded parts become $R(l)_i = R_{l+i}$. Your comment makes me realize that I meant $R(-l_i)$, which I'll correct shortly. Now the $i$th basis element of $\bigoplus R(-l_i)$ that I referred to is just the identity of the direct summand $R(-l_i)$, which lies in degree $l_i$. For the definition of the twist, see: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00JL

Comment: @MannyReyes You say that you have the isomorphism between $G/R_+G$ and $F/R_+F$, but how do you prove that? You need to show that the kernel of the map $G \to F \to F/R_+F$ is $G/R_+G$ -- why is that? And if you don't mind answering, why does $L \subseteq R_+F \oplus R_+L$ imply $L \subseteq R_+L$? Thank you!

Comment: @windsheaf - if helpful: $L\subset R_+F \oplus R_+L$ implies $L\subset R_+L$ because $L$ intersects $F$ only trivially (because $G = F\oplus L$ to begin with), thus $L$ intersects $R_+F\subset F$ only trivially. For the other question, note that in the answer itself Manny is arguing the stronger claim that the map from $G$ to $F$ is an isomorphism. The proof goes through the argument that $G \rightarrow F/R_+F$ is a *surjection* as an intermediate step, and uses the graded Nakayama lemma to conclude that $G\rightarrow F$ is surjective. The rest argues that $G\rightarrow F$ is injective.

Comment: cont'd: (This involves the thing about $L\subset R_+L$, followed by a second application of Nakayama.) Anyway it all arrives at the conclusion that $G\rightarrow F$ is already an isomorphism. From this it follows that $G/R_+G \rightarrow F/R_+F$ is an isomorphism, but that is not really its own step in the argument; it is moreso a guiding intuition. The point is that we built $G$ as a free $R$-module with a basis designed to map to the lifts of a basis of $F/R_+F$ to $F$. Cont'd:

Comment: Let me know if this was helpful -- I can try to explain more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial result for now.

> If $R$ is an $\mathbb N$-graded $K$-algebra and $F$ is a $\mathbb Z$-graded $R$-module which is free of *finite rank*, then $F$ is gr-free.

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be a minimal system of homogeneous generators for $F$. Then their images $\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n$ in $F/R_+F$ generate the $K$-vector space $F/R_+F$, and therefore we can suppose that $\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_m$, $m\le n$, form a $K$-basis in $F/R_+F$. Thus we have $F=R_+F+\langle x_1,\dots,x_m\rangle$, and the graded Nakayama's lemma gives us $F=\langle x_1,\dots,x_m\rangle$ hence $m=n$.
This shows that $\dim_KF/R_+F=n$, so $n=\operatorname{rank}F$. But a system of generators consisting of $\operatorname{rank}F$ elements is necessarily a basis, and we are done.

Comment: For a bit of perspective, the key way in which $K$ being a field is used here is fact that every graded $K$-vector space (in particular, $F/R_+F$) has a homogeneous basis (i.e., that the result holds for $R=K$).

Comment: More generally, the same argument works whenever $K$ is a ring with invariant basis number such that every f.g. projective $K$-module is free (since the graded parts of $F/R_+F$ are direct summands of the free f.g. $K$-module $F/R_+F$ and hence f.g. projective).

Comment: @EricWofsey Hello could you please explain the implication: "This shows that $\dim_KF/R_+F=n$, so $n=\operatorname{rank}F$". I dont see how the dimension of vector space implies the rank of $F$. Regards

Comment: Ah is see. Let $r$=rank(F). Then $r\geq n$ (i.e the basis elements will generate $F/R_+F$ as a $K$-vector space.). Since $x_1,..,x_n$ generate $F$ this implies there exists surjective module homomorphism from $R^n$ to $R^r$ which implies $n\geq r$.