# Projective and free modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module, free-modules, graded-rings

In the graded context, if $R = K[x_1,...,x_n]$ where $K$ is a field, is a projective R-module a free R-module?

Comment: See also the related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen%E2%80%93Suslin_theorem

Comment: Does the "graded context" make this question different from the proposed duplicate?  I can't see how...

Comment: @rschwieb: Yes it does, since a priori a graded module could be free as an (ungraded) module but not as a graded module (i.e., it has no basis consisting of homogeneous elements).

Comment: This can't happen for graded modules that are bounded below (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557402/graded-free-is-stronger-than-graded-and-free)), but I don't know about the general case for modules over a polynomial ring.

Comment: @EricWofsey I see. So maybe all one can say is that all projective graded modules are free as ungraded modules, but there's a gap after that point concluding that they are free as graded modules.  Thank you for reopening it. I was about to based on your comment.

Comment: I know there are theorems that under very mild hypotheses any non finitely generated projective module is free. I don’t know the proofs of these off the top of my head though so I don’t know whether they still work in a graded context.

Comment: Maybe Kaplansky's Theorem 2 (any projective module over a local ring is free) in his paper "Projective Modules" (Ann. Math. 68 (1958), 372-377) works in the graded case.

Comment: By the way, you should specify the grading on the ring $R$. If you set $\deg x_j = 0$ for all $j$, then the "graded context" is not the same as if $\deg x_j = 1$.