# Criteria for local freeness of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a finite type module over a local ring $R$. If the minimum number of generators equals the maximum number of independent elements, is $M$ free? If not, do you have a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to assume $R$ local in order to show that $M$ is free.

Suppose that $M$ can be generated by $n$ elements. Then there exists $R^n\to M$ a surjective homomorphism. Denote by $x_1,\dots,x_n$ a linear independent subset of $M$ and by $N$ the submodule of $M$ generated by $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Then there is an isomorphism $N\to R^n$. This way we get a surjective homomorphism $N\to M$ and this is [necessarily](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239364/surjective-endomorphisms-of-finitely-generated-modules-are-isomorphisms/239445#239445) an isomorphism, so $M$ is free.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and the very instructive link. Clear & elegant.

Comment: @brunoh Thanks. I've just realized that this is a duplicate :( (See question 4) in the linked topic.)

Comment: unfortunately yes it is. But I found the question duplicated you mentioned quite instructive too. Was worth it. Thank you.