# Surjectivity implies injectivity of finitely generated modules, localization?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, finitely-generated

The following problem is canonical:

> Suppose $A$ is a commutative unitary ring, and $M$ is a finitely generated module over $A$. If an endomorphism $f\colon M\to M$ is surjective, then it's also injective.

It appears in Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*, or [another MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239364/23875). There're two canonical ways to crack it. However, I'm considering another method, but get stuck at some point. I wonder whether my method could be completed. I want some help on this.

First, note that injectivity and surjectivity are local properties, we can assume that $(A,m)$ is a local ring and $k=A/m$ is the residue field of $m$. Now we tensor the following exact sequence
$$0\to N=\ker f\to M\xrightarrow f M\to 0$$
and obtain a new exact sequence
$$N\otimes_A k\to M\otimes_A k\xrightarrow{f\otimes1}M\otimes_A k\to 0$$
Since $M$ is finitely generated, $M\otimes_A k$ is finite dimensional over $k$, $f\otimes1$ is surjective therefore an isomorphism, thus the image of $N\otimes_A k$ in $M\otimes_A k$ is zero, therefore $N\subseteq mM$. However, I don't know how to proceed then. I want to take advantage of Nakayama's lemma.

Well, as user26857 said, there's no evidence that $N$ is immediately finitely-generated, so even if $N\otimes_A k=0$, $N$ needn't be $0$. I don't know whether $N\subseteq mM$ could be used to lift the inverse map of $f\otimes1$, etc. The next step is still unclear.

Note that if $f\otimes1$ is surjective, by Nakayama's lemma, $f$ is also surjective, so the reduction is somewhat safe. Note also that $M\otimes_A k$ is also fiber of the module $M$ over $m$, and the pattern is quite similar to inverse function theorem in smooth category, which lifts a linear isomorphism to a local diffeomorphism.

Any help? Thanks!

**Remark:** For completeness, here's the proof on Eisenbud's book:

We may regard $M$ as a module over $A[X]$, letting $X$ act by $X.m=f(m)$ for $m\in M$. If we set $I=(X)$, then since $f$ is surjective, $IM=M$ and by a version of Nakayama's lemma, there exists $g\in A[X]$ such that $(1-g(X)X)M=0$, therefore $1-g(f)f=0$, thus $g(f)$ is the inverse to $f$.

If somebody could point out a nice geometric viewpoint of the preceding proof, it could also be a good answer.

Comment: @user26857 Maybe $N$ isn't essential.

Comment: I doubt that the proof works. Base change to the residue field loses too much information. One has to use other arguments. At the moment I have 4 proofs for the statement. For example, the usual arguments let us reduce to the case that $A$ is of finite type and hence noetherian. But then $M$ is noetherian, hence Hopfian.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I didn't understand your point, but by Nakayama, the surjectivity of $M\otimes_k k\xrightarrow{f\otimes1}M\otimes_k k$ implies the surjectivity of $M\xrightarrow fM$. See, for example, Atiyah & Macdonald, Ex 2.10.

Comment: Of course I know that. But you want to show that $f$ is injective. And for this the residue field is not enough.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yeah, it might be frustrating. Incidentally, is there any geometric viewpoint of viewing $M$ as an $A[X]$ module by action $X.m=f(m)$?

Comment: The idea in Eisenbud is due to a guy named Vasconcelos, I think. Note he's using Cayley Hamilton.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Why'd he delete this one?

Comment: @user26857 Right, but I only asked for a geometric meaning, not claimed that there should be. I asked since I feel that I don't really understand the determinant trick and it's still a very tricky stuff to me. I don't understand the underlying reason why viewing $M$ as an $A[X]$-module is that efficient, say, to obtain Frobenius normal forms for matrices, or in proof of Nakayama's lemma.