# Surjectivity of a Free Module Homomorphism implies Injectivity?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ be a free $R$-module having a finite basis of $n$ elements.
>   Let $T:M\to M$ be a surjective $R$-module homomorphism.
>   Then $T$ is injective.

Let $I$ be a maximal ideal of $R$.
Note that $I$ annihilates $\widehat M:=M/IM$ and thus $\widehat M$ is an $\bar (R/I)$-module.
Write $\bar R=R/I$.

For each $r\in R$, write $\bar r$ to denote $r+I$ and for each $m\in M$ write $\widehat m$ to denote $m+IM$.

Define $\widetilde T:\widehat M\to \widehat M$ as
    $$\widetilde T(\widehat m)=\widehat{Tm},\quad \forall \widehat m\in \widehat M$$
It is easy to see that $\widetilde T$ is well defined.
Note that $\widetilde T$ is a surjective linear operator on a vector space and hence is also injective.

Note that if $\mathcal B=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis of $M$, then $\widehat B=\{\widehat e_1,\ldots,\widehat e_n\}$ is a basis for $\widehat M$.

Now suppose $T(r_1e_1+\cdots+r_ne_n)=0$.

Then we get $\widetilde T(\bar r_1\widehat e_1+\cdots+\bar r_n\widehat e_n)=\widehat 0$.
Since $\widetilde T$ is injective, we get $\bar r_i=\bar 0$ for all $i$.
But this doesn't lead to $r_i=0$.

Can anybody see how to complete the proof from here?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874799/surjectivity-implies-injectivity-of-finitely-generated-modules-localization?rq=1) including the comments.

Comment: I do not know anything about tensors so I haven't read it.

Comment: Well, the $M\otimes k$ in the other question is just your $\widehat{M}$.

Comment: Thanks. But it is still too advanced for me. I have just started reading module theory. Read the concept of a free module and some obvious questions came to mind.

Comment: Consensus of the comments to the other question: you might be loosing too much information by looking at the residue fields. If you don't know the Nakayama lemma, then I think you have to make use of freeness. Suppose it were vector spaces, how would you construct the inverse map?

Comment: In case of vector spaces I had the rank-nullity theorem. Let me see if an inverse map can be directly constructed. Never thought of it this way.