# Characterization of free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a commutative ring $A$. Is it true that if there exists a positive integer $n$ and a pair of homomorphisms $\pi:A^n\rightarrow M$ and $\phi:A^n\rightarrow M$ such that $\pi$ is surjective and $\phi$ is injective then $M\cong A^n$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is.

Let $N=\phi(A^n)$. Then $N$ is a submodule of $M$ isomorphic to $A^n$. Now define $f:N\to M$ by $f(\phi(x))=\pi(x)$. Then $f$ is surjective, and [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/239445/121097) injective. We thus get that $M$ is free of rank $n$.

Comment: Why does $f$ exist?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg $f$ is this composition: $\phi(A^n)\simeq A^n\stackrel{\pi}\to M$.

Comment: Alright, but $f$ is not an endomorphism, and therefore the result doesn't apply.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg M. Orzech proved that it is not necessary to be an endomorphism: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2316897?uid=3737528&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21104550594211

Comment: I didn't know it, thank you!