# When is a surjective homomorphism with a right-inverse an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group (or more generally a module over a ring $R$) and $\phi:G\to G$ a surjective group homomorphism with a *right-inverse* $\psi: G\to G$, i.e. $\phi\circ \psi = id_G$.
So, we have a $split$ short exact sequence
$$
0\to K:=\ker(\phi)\to G\overset{\phi}{\to} G\to 0
$$
and hence $G\cong K\oplus G$.

> **Question:** Under which conditions on $G$ can we conclude that $\phi$ is an isomorphism (i.e. that $K=0$)?

I suspect that there is a notion/name for such groups $G$ that I'm ignorant of. So, references are very welcome as well.
Thanks in advance for any contribution.

Comment: If $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group or module over a noetherian ring, every surjective endomorphism of $G$ is an isomorphism (the verification is easy). If the ring is not noetherian, the same is true, but the proof (though short) is not so obvious (it is a result by Vasconcelos, I think). On the other side, there are surjective endomorphisms of a free not finitely generated abelian group (and so split) that are not isomorphisms: take $F\oplus F\to F$ surjective not injective and sum to each side an infinite number of copies of $F$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239364/surjective-endomorphisms-of-finitely-generated-modules-are-isomorphisms

Comment: Have you heard of *hopfian* groups? Anyway if your abelian group $G$ is finitely generated (as a group) then your $K = 0$.

Comment: @A.G. Thanks for your comment. The groups I'm interested in (in particular $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$) are typically not finitely generated.

Comment: @M.U.  Thanks for the reference to *Hopfian Groups*, I'll definitely look into that.