# Does $M \oplus N \cong M$ imply that $N = 0$ for modules $M,N$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, direct-sum

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M,N$ be $R$-modules. Does $M \oplus N \cong M$ imply that $N = 0$?

I would think that  $M \oplus N \cong M$ implies that $(M \oplus N)/M \cong M/M = 0$, but is that true? And if yes, how would the first isomorphism induce the second one? Sorry if this question has been answered before, I could not find an answer.

Edit: And what if $M$ is assumed to be finitely generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $M$ is finitely generated. Let $f:M \xrightarrow{\cong} M \oplus N$ be an isomorphism and let $p:M \oplus N \to M$ be the projection on the first factor.
Now $p \circ f:M \to M$ is a surjective endomorphism. It is hence an isomorphism, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239364/348926). Now as $p\circ f$ and $f$ are both isomorphisms, so is $p = (p \circ f) \circ f^{-1}$. But the kernel of $p$ is $N$, so $N=0$

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Thanks a lot, now I can sleep well ;)

Answer (score 4):

> I would think that  $M \oplus N \cong M$ implies that $(M \oplus N)/M \cong M/M = 0$, but is that true?

As you've already seen from the other answers, this argument doesn't work. Don't let the notation fool you too much; if you just have some arbitrary isomorphism $\varphi : M \oplus N \cong M$, then when you write "$M/M$" what you really mean is $\varphi^{-1}(M)/M$, or $M/\varphi(M)$. There are two different copies of $M$ here which the notation is fooling you into identifying! Your argument requires the much stronger condition that the isomorphism $M \oplus N \cong M$ is the natural projection $M \oplus N \to M$, so that the two copies of $M$ involved are the same. This is a good example of the difference between a natural isomorphism and an "unnatural" isomorphism.

Comment: Do you know whether it is true in case $M$ is finitely generated? It seems to me that is should be true (using a minimal generating systen), but I am unable to write down a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, that is in general not true. Not even if both of them are free and over a field. Consider $M=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}=N$.

**Added:**
In case you also assume that $M$ is finitely generated, then it becomes true if you have no torsion and $R$ is an integral ring. We can define $n(M)=:L$ to be the maximal cardinality of a linearly indepedent (over $R$) family in $M$ ($L$ is finite as $M$ is finitely generated and $R$ an integral ring). One readily checks that this number is preserved under isomorphism. However, if $N$ was different from $\{0\}$, then we can take $((x_1,0), \dots, (x_L,0), (0,s))$ with $s\neq 0$. As we have no torsion, we get that $n(M)=n(M\oplus N)\geq n(M)+1$, which gives you a contradiction.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net That is also not required. Surely they are isomorphic (they have the same dimension).

Comment: Thanks for this. What if we add the assumption that M is finitely generated?

Comment: Sorry I misread $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ to $\mathbb R^n$ with $n$ finite.I’ll delete my comment.

Comment: If M and N are both finetly generated and free your assumption holds (this is exercise 2.11 in Atiyah MacDonald)

Comment: Interesting. I don't know on the spot. But I'll think about it :)

Comment: @NicoW $M$ and $N$ are not assumed to be free, as then the result directly follows from IBN for commutative rings, right?

Comment: @NicoW Sure, then the we can consider the rank.

Comment: @EinStone: I have some version, but I would guess it is far from optimal.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Again thanks for the proof in the case R integral and M torsion free. Is there a counterexample for non integral domains and/or modules with torsion?

Comment: @EinStone there is not such counterexample, because it's always true if M is finitely generated and R is commutative, see my answer.

Comment: @LukasHeger Thanks so much, problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

None. For example, let $M = \oplus_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb Z$ and $N = \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks for this. What if we add the assumption that M is finitely generated?

Comment: The answer is no in general. For noncommutative ring, the invariance of basis number theorem fails to hold. There are some funny noncommutative ring $R$ such that $R = R\oplus R$.

Comment: @Hydrogen Surely it is false in the noncommutative setting. Do you also know an example in the commutative setting where $M$ is finitely generated? I cannot come up with one and would be curious to see one :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Okay, I think I overlook the condition 'commutative'. For commutative case, I have no idea....

Comment: @Hydrogen: In case something comes to your mind, I'd be really eager to learn about it!