# Injective endomorphism is an automorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

There seems to be a well-known result in commutative algebra that if $A$ is a commutative ring with unity and $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module then any surjective endomorphism $f : M \to M$ is necessarily an automorphism. My reference for this fact is Eisenbud's GTM150 commutative algebra book Corollary 4.4 (or more directly, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239364/surjective-endomorphisms-of-finitely-generated-modules-are-isomorphisms)).

Of course the above property fails for injective endomorphisms, as we have simple examples such as $A = k[x]$, $M = A$ with $f$ a multiplication map by $x$.

Now let $X$ be a projective variety over a field $k$ and $F$ a coherent sheaf on it. Say $f : F \to F$ is its endomorphism. If $f$ is surjective then the above commutative algebra fact says $f$ is an automorphism. My question is:
if $f$ is injective, is $f$ an isomorphism?

My attempt was the following. Say we have a short exact sequence $0 \to F \to F \to C \to 0$. Fix any ample line bundle on $X$ and associate Hilbert polynomials to $F$ and $C$. By the short exact sequence, this forces the Hilbert polynomial associated to $C$ to be a constant $0$, forcing $C$ to be the zero sheaf. This also works when $f$ is surjective.

Is this proof correct? I'm a little worried since I couldn't find any reference for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer the question by myself, to prevent any potential confusion by the statement (like I did).

My original attempt was a correct proof, and in fact it has the following equivalent commutative algebra formulation: let $S$ be a finitely generated graded algebra over $k$ (commutative with 1) and $M$ a finitely generated graded $S$-module. Then any injective (resp. surjective) graded $S$-module homomorphism $f : M \to M$ is automatically bijective.

The proof for this is simple, because each degree $M_i$ are finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces, so an injectivity (resp. surjectivity) of a $k$-linear map $f : M_i \to M_i$ implies it is bijective. It is interesting to compare this to the original non-graded commutative algebra version, which I believe is much more subtle.

I have no idea if the statement would still hold if $X$ is only proper over $k$.